# List of files changed since a certain date using SVN

Tags: svn

What kind of SVN command can I run that will get me a list of files changed since a certain date?

Right now I have it as

```
svn log <url> -r {2010-11-01}:{2011-05-04} > log.txt
```

That almost work, but it only shows the revisions and comments but not the files list.

Comment: if you use `-v` you will get a list of files embedded in each commit log entry. if youre just trying to assemble a cumulative list though this probably isnt what you want

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Add the `--verbose` (or `-v`) flag and you'll get a list of all affected paths as well as the log messages.  If you want to get rid of the messages, add the `--quiet` (or `-q`) flag.  So:

```
svn log <url> -qv -r {2010-11-01}:{2011-05-04} > log.txt
```

Comment: svn log <url> -qv -r \{2010-11-01\}:\{2011-05-04\} > log.txt

Answer (score 42):

If you just want each changed file printed once (rather than for each revision in which it was changed), you could also do:

```
svn diff <url> --summarize -r {2010-11-01}:{2011-05-04} > log.txt
```

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't show files that experienced a reversion in that time frame.

Comment: Do you mean files on which `svn revert` was used?  If so, no method through the VCS will help you, since, by definition, a `revert` ensures that no changes are recorded.

Answer (score 5):

> With --verbose, svn log will also
>   print all affected paths with each log
>   message.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html