# List of files NOT changed since a certain date using SVN

Tags: svn

I'm managing a software package that is under heavy development by many people. However, some parts of the package may be no longer needed and could possibly be removed. A good indicator for this would be if no change happened for a long time. [You'll have to trust me on this. The collaboration I'm in has very strange working habits...]

How can I find out which files in an SVN repo did **not** change for a certain timespan?

I've found this question, which describes the inverse of my problem:
[List of files changed since a certain date using SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891256/list-of-files-changed-since-a-certain-date-using-svn)

However, it's not clear to me how I could use the answers given to solve my problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have some options

1. get `svn info file` , extract revision from output. If file revision << repostory revision, then this file is too old
2. get `svn info --xml` and parse the xml results for file/folder revisions
3. do the `svn checkout` with `use-commit-times` options and search for old files in working copy

Answer (score 0):

If you have `grep` (and you have to have grep even on Windows), you can

- Get list of changed paths in file FILE (see linked answer)
- Pipe list of all files in repo into special grep: `svn ls -R | grep -v -f FILE` (TBT!!! I  have not grep in hands right now)

  - `svn ls -R` in the root of WC output the full tree
  - grep -f uses patterns for search from file (line per line), -v inverse results, i.e. *I expect* in output strings from ls, not found in FILE, as it was requested

Answer (score 0):

First, get a list unique list of files/folders that have been recently changed. Go to the root of your working copy and execute

```
 svn log <url> -qv -r {startdate}:{enddate} | grep "^ " | awk '{print $2}' | sort -u | cut -c<N>- > changed.txt
```

Please note that this command assumes that you have no spaces in your filenames. If there are spaces, you need to replace the `awk` command with something more sophisticated. The integer `<N>` in the `cut` command should be chosen such that all paths in `changed.txt` are relative to the current directory.

Then, get a similar list of all currently existing files:

```
find . -type f -not -path "*/.svn*" | sort -u  | cut -c3- > current.txt
```

Finally, get the list of currently existing files that have not been changed recently (i.e. files that are present in `current.txt` but not in `changed.txt`):

```
comm -23 current.txt changed.txt
```